# Can Xcode LLDB watch a Object-C variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a class, whose superclass is UIScrollView, just like this:

```swift
class MailSendContainerView: UIScrollView {

}
```

but When I use my Xcode LLDB to watch its frame change, I got an error like this:

```swift
 watch set var -w write self.scrollContainer.frame
error: "frame" is not a member of "(MailSDK.MailSendContainerView) self.some.scrollContainer"
```

I wonder whether it is because that the frame of UIView is a `CGRect`, which is a struct.

Can anybody tell me why, and is there any way to watch it? Thank you.

Swift 5.5 Xcode 12.5

### Edit

I simply tried to watch a `CGRect`, this way I got an Error tells the size of `CGRect` is too big for watching. So I tried to watch a Struct which only has a `Int` property in it, and it's OK. It's also OK to watch the component of `CGRect` such as `origin.x` like @Caleb said.

So I think the problem is not its type. And because I also can't watch the variable `view` in a `viewController`, which comes an error like `cannot find variable name 'view' in this frame`, I think this is something about inheritance or Object-C? But I'm not sure.

Still need answers, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder whether it is because that the frame of UIView is a CGRect, which is a struct.

The error you're seeing is due to the fact that `UIView` doesn't have a `frame` instance variable; `frame` is a property, i.e. a method, that calculates the frame rectangle and returns it. Try inspecting a `UIView` instance in the debugger and look at it's instance variables; you won't find one called `frame` or `_frame`.

But I think your speculation is also correct: IIRC the debugger will complain if you try to watch a struct or anything else that's not a native type. One way around that, especially for something as small as a `CGRect`, is to just watch the component values like `origin.x`, `origin.y`, `width`, and `height` instead.

Comment: Hi @Caleb, thanks for your answer. Because of the character limitation of comment, so I add it to the problem, you can take a look if you like. And I think about `frame`, actually I can use `addObserver` to observe its changes, and this property can also be set directly like `a.frame = ...`, and I search for the implement of frame but I find nothing, so I wonder what do you mean when you say `frame` is "calculated"? Did I misunderstand something? Thanks for your answers again! :)

Comment: Did you mean that `frame` is actually from `CALayer`?